# Rank base on a column in one table

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have a simple table `User` with two attribute `ID` and `AGE`
Now I want to get a 'rank' result base on `AGE`

```
 User Table

ID      AGE
0        23
1        35
2        30
3        52
4        35
5        23
6        19
```

If I do `select * from User order by AGE ASC` I can easily get a sorted result as below:

```
ID      AGE
6        19
0        23
5        23
2        30
1        35
4        35
3        52
```

But what I really want to get is :

```
ID      RANK
6        0
0        1
5        1
2        3
1        4
4        4
3        6
```

I have come up with pretty good solution below, but it has a tiny imperfection

```
SELECT U1.ID, count(*) AS RANK
FROM User U1, User U2
WHERE U1.age > U2.age
GROUP BY U1.ID ORDER BY RANK;
```

This gives me:

```
ID      RANK
0        1
5        1
2        3
1        4
4        4
3        6
```

It's correct except I lose the one ranking zero cause `WHERE U1.age > U2.age` is never true for the youngest user.

Please shed some light on this problem, thanks in advance!

Comment: Why did you also tag this with Postgres **and** MySQL? It can be solved very easily using the `rank()` or `dense_rank()` function in Postgres. And if you are *not* using MySQL, the accepted answer is extremely bad for performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.id, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM User t2 WHERE t2.AGE < t1.AGE)
AS rnk
FROM User t1 order by rnk ;
```

**[Sample fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/969cf8/8)**

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately MySQL still lacks support for analytic functions. One way to emulate `RANK()` in MySQL

```
SELECT id, rank
  FROM
(
  SELECT id, @n := @n + 1, @r := IF(@a = age, @r, @n) rank, @a := age
    FROM user CROSS JOIN (SELECT @n := -1, @r := -1, @a := NULL) i
   ORDER BY age
) q
```

Output:

```
| ID | RANK |
|----|------|
|  6 |    0 |
|  0 |    1 |
|  5 |    1 |
|  2 |    3 |
|  1 |    4 |
|  4 |    4 |
|  3 |    6 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83b884/10)** demo

---

You should've told in your question that you actually using Postgres in the first place.'

Unfortunately @t-clausen.dk deleted his answer that is absolutely correct in the light of the discovered fact of you using Postgres which supports analytic functions

```
SELECT ID, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY age) - 1 rank
  FROM "user"
```

That is **the best** way to do it.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/7b8cd/2)** demo

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know the difference. And thank you for posting this.